# Enabling errors in php, certain errors are not shown

Tags: php, mysqli

I have certain problems with error reporting in php. I know that it doesn't report them by default, so i tried every solution i found online.

I used the following code inside my php file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

And i also edited the php.ini file. Right now it looks like this:

```
; display_errors
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: On

; display_startup_errors
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: On

; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
;   Development Value: E_ALL 
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

It works up to a certain point. Errors like syntax errors, for example a missing semicolons show, but when i fix them in my code, i get once again the blank screen.
So i believe certain errors still don't show.

The code causing this is a simple php registration form:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'maindatabase');

$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);




 function NewUser()
{
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];          
    $lname = $_POST['lname']; 
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];    
    $password =  $_POST['password'];   

    $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $fname);
    $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $lname);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $email);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $username);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password);
    $query = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, Email) VALUES ('$username','$password','$fname','$lname','$email')"); 

    if($query)
    {
    echo "sucess";
    }
}




if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        NewUser();
}

?>
```

I guess there is some sort of fatal error not showing?
What would that be?

Basically what i am asking is what type of error (in the above code and in general) is not displayed, when syntax errors do?

Can someone please give me some perspective, i have tried everything i found on the internet and still nothing.

I am using xampp, on windows 7.

Comment: Not sure what else may be wrong, but it looks like `$db` is undefined in the scope of your function. You need to pass it as an argument to the function.

Comment: I removed the function and placed the code inside the if(isset($_POST['submit'])) line, still the same result, i get the blank page.

Comment: Look further down the `php.ini` file you showed the informational comments at the top of the file, now look for the actual parameter setting further down the file!

Comment: ALso each `mysqli_` statement can generate a good/bad status Add some code to look for the possibility that one of the mysqli_ commands returned an error. Specifically `mysqli_connect()` and `mysqli_query()` See the manual for [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) and [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Thanks, but still nothing.
I looked at the ini, found the lines 
error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT and display_errors=On , they were both like that and not the ones in the comments, so nothing from there.
i used the mysqli_connect_errno() function and it shows the database is properly connected, so i guess the problem lies somewhere else. Maybe it's something with the columns failing to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error causes a fatal compile-time error, then your script will never even execute, meaning the ini_set() call will never occur.

You need to set them at the php.ini level, so they'll be in effect when PHP starts up, not AFTER your script has (maybe) started executing.

Comment: I have already edited the php.ini file, specifically the display_errors and error_reporting lines. 
Is there another line i need to edit? To catch those fatal errors? Which one would that be?

Comment: you .ini sample is all comments. there's no active settings in there at all.

Comment: Oh, really? This is how it was by default, with ; in front of all lines.
I removed it from the display_errors and error_reporting ones and still nothing.
Should i remove more or something?